# Question on a proof related to Iwasawa's theorem in Washington's "Introduction to cyclotomic fields"

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I've been stumbling through Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields (2nd edition)" and chapter §13.3 on Iwasawa's theorem has some claims that I am having a hard time with.

The chapter starts off with a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension $K_\infty/K$, so $Gal(K_n/K) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. For each extension $K_n$ let $L_n$ be its maximal unramified abelian p-extension.

Next comes the assumption that is used for the first half of the chapter.

**Assumption**: *All primes which are ramified in $K_\infty/K$ are totally ramified.*

The author claims that from the assumption it follows that $K_{n+1}\cap L_n = K_n$, and from this $Gal(L_n/K_n)\simeq Gal(L_nK_{n+1}/K_{n+1})$. Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks:

- There must be some prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ above $p$ that is ramified in $K_\infty/K$. This is simply because $K_\infty/K$ is an infinite abelian extension and class field theory tells us that the maximal unramified abelian extension is finite over $K$.
- If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime that totally ramifies in $K_\infty/K$, then it also (totally) ramifies in any subextension $M/L$ with $K \subset L \subset M \subset K_\infty$. Thus $(K_{n+1} \cap L_n)/K_n$ is totally ramified at $\mathfrak{p}$, but $L_n/K_n$ is unramified everywhere, hence $(K_{n+1} \cap L_n)/K$ must also be unramified everywhere. This is only possible if $K_{n+1} \cap L_n$ is the trivial extension of $K_n$.
- For any finite Galois extension $L/K$ and finite extension $M/K$, Galois theory gives a canonical identification $\mathrm{Gal}(ML/M) \cong \mathrm{Gal}(L/ L \cap M)$. Thus $\mathrm{Gal}(L_{n} K_{n+1} / K_{n+1}) \cong \mathrm{Gal}(L_n/ (L_n \cap K_{n+1})) = \mathrm{Gal}(L_n/K_n).$

Comment: sorry but I guess that something should be changed in remark 2: $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $K$ so it does not make sense to say that $(K_{n+1}\cap L_n)|K_n$ is totally ramified at $\mathfrak p$ (since $\mathfrak p$ is not a prime of $K_n$ in general). Could you clarify this?

Comment: You mean that the prime of $K_n$ above $\mathfrak p$ is totally ramified too in $(K_{n+1}\cap L_n)|K_n$. Do you agree? If one looks at the corresponding inertia groups, I think I have an argument that shows it.

Comment: There is a unique prime lying over $\mathfrak p$ in any totally ramified extension, so when I say that $M/L$ is totally ramified at $\mathfrak{p}$ I simply mean that it is totally ramified at the unique prime of $L$ lying above $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Hey Brandon, maybe you could be interested also in this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833612/a-unit-of-an-extension-of-a-totally-real-field-herbrands-theorem I would like to have an help. I do not even understand if the answer is trivial or not. I do not think that the answer is straightforward, but nobody answers so I am not sure. It would be nice to have just some sketchy ideas.